# OpenCV - how to prioritize opencv libraries compiled in /home over those from /usr/lib/ using Eclipse C++ IDE

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I want to setup an OpenCV project in Linux using Eclipse IDE in C++.

First, I have compiled my own version of OpenCV using the [instructions](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) mentioned on the openCV website in my `/home/` directory. After this, I wanted to setup a basic show image project using Eclipse IDE following [their instructions](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html).

However, I am using OpenSUSE 12.2 and I have an older, preinstalled version of OpenCV in `/usr/` and when I build the project and check the linked libraries of OpenCV with the `ldd` command applied to the generated binary, it points out to the library files from `/usr/lib64/`.

In order to point out to the compiled library files from my home library I had to modify the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable from `.bashrc` file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/OpenCV/release/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Following this, I started the Eclipse IDE from a terminal with the reinitialized `.bashrc` file.
After this step it worked. However, is there a way to prioritize the `/home/` path over the `/usr/` path from Eclipse IDE instead of doing the `./bashrc` trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try run your program after setting LD_PRELOAD environmental variable, pointing to your libraries that you want to be loaded first.

You can prepare a script to lauch your program:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=./your_library.so
./your_program
```